# Central Limit Theorem - Formulation of the Result

Tags: statistics, central-limit-theorem

While working on GLM and related methods I encountered a strange formulation of the central limit theorem: For the (quasi) score functions $U_\beta$,  [Peter McCullagh (1983)](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176346056) states for example:
$$
N^{-1/2} U_\beta \sim N(0,\sigma^2i_\beta/N) + O_p(N^{-\frac{1}{2}})
$$
He claims that this result should follow from the central limit theorem.

Does anyone know which central limit theorem they used to obtain the rates of convergences as the above statement is clearly more informative than just saying

$$N^{-1/2} U_\beta \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2i_\beta/N).$$

Comment: I've not read the paper, but I guess it follows from the Barry-Essen theorem.

Comment: hm, barry-essen, seems to go in the right direction somehow, but i can not see that it fits 100%: the theorem gives a statement about the cumulative distribution function of a mean, which is not a random variable, while the above formulation clearly states that there is some randomness involved.